# value of a complex integration along a curve

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\gamma$ be a closed and continuously differentiable path in the upper half plane

$\{z\in C: z= x+iy, x\in R, y\in R, y\gt 0 \}$

not passing through the point $i$. Describe the set of all possible values of the integral $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma} \frac{2i}{z^2+1} dz$$

If $f$ doesn't contain $i$ then the value would be zero. If $f$ contains $i$ then it would be $1$.

But is this all??

Comment: are you familiar with residue calculus?

Comment: yes.. Know it ..

Comment: then...? what are the poles of $z^2+1$ in $\gamma$? what would be $\int _{\gamma} f(z)dz$ when you know residues of poles of $f(z)$ in $\gamma$?

Comment: How can it be all integer values??

Comment: who said it will be all integer values? I did not said that :O you have not even tried what i have said :O

Comment: Either way I got 1 or 0??

Comment: when will it be one? when will it be zero?

Comment: nothing more than that

Comment: SInce $f$ doesn't pass through $-i$ the only pole would be at $i$. If $f$ passes through it then $1$ else $0$.??

Comment: fine.. are you familiar with winding number concept?

Comment: be sure of what you are saying...It is already said that $\gamma$ does not pass through $i$... I suppose by $f$ you mean $\gamma$ in your  last comment

Comment: yeah $\gamma$..

Comment: NOt aware of winding number concept...

Comment: if you do not know winding number that is fine... Now tell me if there is any restriction that $\gamma$ should be just circle or any closed path? if it is circle it would contain $i$ only once... If it is not don't you think there is a possibility that $\gamma$ contains $i$ more than once by which i mean when you go around $\gamma$ you  would see $i$ more than once at different points on its "left side"??

Comment: There is no restriction on $\gamma$. It may go .

Comment: then.... you would use your residue theorem that many number of times and conclude that integral can be (?????)

Comment: I do not understand your point when you say "will even pass through it" it is already mentioned that it will not pass through $i$

Comment: There is so much at stake here. What is the guarantee that the curve will even contain it?? Even if it does, how can it lie to the left?? The  no of times the curve passes (say k times) then answer will be k. What about negative integers??

Comment: suppose it does not contain then it would be just zero... we do integration on counterclockwise so all idiots will be in our left side..

Comment: okay..what about negative integers??

Comment: Negative numbers case is not very obvious (at least to me)... I feel they should be included but then i could not immediately explain the argument... :O  I am sure It is not so difficult... As you have so many questions on basics I would suggest you to look at some complex analysis book on residue theorem/winding number topics....

Comment: I would suggest you to edit the question so it would bump again in main list and somebody may respond!